# php 5.6.20 - /etc/php5/conf.d directory missing

Tags: linux, php, php5, php.ini

I can't find /etc/php5/conf.d directory in my system. 
Do they change catalog structure ?

I already read [/usr/share/doc/php5-common/README.Debian.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383806/what-the-ini-files-in-etc-php5-conf-d-folder-are-for)
There is information about linking /etc/php5/$SAPI/conf.d to central directory **/etc/php5/conf.d** which is not present in my directory

```
root@d0:/# ls -al /etc/php5/
razem 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 maj 20 10:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 68 root root 4096 maj 20 10:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 maj 20 10:16 apache2
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 maj 20 10:50 cgi
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 maj 20 10:16 cli
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 maj 20 10:16 mods-available

root@d0:/# dpkg -l | grep php
ii  libapache2-mod-php5            5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-apc                        4.0.7-1                   all          APC User Cache for PHP 5 (transitional package)
ii  php5                           5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-apcu                      4.0.7-1                   amd64        APC User Cache for PHP 5
ii  php5-cgi                       5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                       5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                    5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                      5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        CURL module for php5
ii  php5-gd                        5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        GD module for php5
ii  php5-imagick                   3.2.0~rc1-1               amd64        Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
ii  php5-imap                      5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        IMAP module for php5
ii  php5-json                      1.3.6-1                   amd64        JSON module for php5
ii  php5-ldap                      5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        LDAP module for php5
ii  php5-mcrypt                    5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        MCrypt module for php5
ii  php5-mysqlnd                   5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
ii  php5-recode                    5.6.20+dfsg-0+deb8u1      amd64        recode module for php5
```

Comment: Isn't it located under cli/ directory?

Comment: It is, but what I need to do is to paste apc configure file to php. CLI is Comand Line Interface. So what I should do: create conf.d folder, paste file in cli/conf.d or apache2/conf.d or... cgi/conf.d ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Look in `/etc/php/mods-available` dir and use `sudo php5enmod`

Yes, they have changed the directory structure.

/etc/php5/**conf.d**

was present in previous Debian releases and has been supported in Debian 7 (wheezy), but, starting with Debian 8 (jessie) you have to use the directory

/etc/php5/**mods-available**

In Debian 8 you are supposed to use `php5enmod`/`php5dismod` utilities to create/remove necessary symlinks in `/etc/php5/cli`, `/etc/php5/apache2`, etc.

For example: if in Debian 7 you could create `/etc/php5/99-local.ini` file and manually add symlinks to this file from `/etc/php5/cli`, `/etc/php5/apache2`, etc., now you must:

1. create `/etc/php5/mods-available/local.ini` file
2. add `; priority=99` line to that file if priority is important to you
3. run `sudo php5enmod local`

Note that `php5enmod` is not included in normal user's path, so don't expect command-line autocomplete to know this utility.

Answer (score 2):

If somebody has same problem: 
Default ini file for apc is now located in: /etc/php5/**mods-available/** 
Thank you for your time.